# How to get PHP to upgrade to a later version of Curl?

Tags: php, curl

Curl 7.64.0 has a bug where it's not able to save cookies using cookiejar from a domain name that does not contain a dot (`.`).

This makes using a local server with authentication impossible. because I access it using its own name and the name has no dots in it. eg: "SERVERNAME/LOGIN"

When searching "How to upgrade Curl version on php" the only answer that I read is:

> You need to download another version of php and copy php_curl.dll to the PHP/EXT folder.

The problem is that PHP 7.3, PHP 7.2 and PHP 7.1 all are using this 7.64 version of CURL. And trying to download php_curl.dll from PHP 7.0 makes curl not working. I get "function curl does not exist" errors everywhere - I restarted IIS after copying it, so that's not an option either.

How can I downgrade or upgrade this version of curl and keep the same PHP version? Should I install PHP 7.0 which is outdated and insecure?

How can I find diferent versions of PHP_Curl and how should I upgrade them?

### Edit

cURL associative response

> This "features" value does not have the PSL bit set (1<<20) which
>   means this curl version suffers from a cookie parsing bug present in
>   7.64.0, fixed in
>   7.64.1 (commit 299d9660f85), that made curl not accept cookies on domain names without any dots.
>
> Solution: upgrade (or downgrade) curl.

by daniel.haxx.se

PHP acknowledged the bug here https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78162

> Thanks for reporting!  I can confirm this issue.
>
> However, upgrading to cURL 7.64.1 is blocked by bug #78007, upgrading
>   to cURL 7.65.0/1 by bug #78100.  Downgrading is also no option due to
>   CVE fixes, which have been applied to the libcurl-7.64.0-3 packages.
>
> We certainly have to keep an eye on this.

Comment: I think this does not belong to SO, as it's not a programming issue. You should have tried on Server Fault instead to ask.

Comment: I had no clue I had to post there, sorry

Comment: what platform are you using? this is very relevant. are you using Linux? Windows? MacOS? BSD?~

Comment: can you link to cURL bug?

Comment: I asked Directly in the mailing list on cURL, they didn't specify the links to the bug but I will update the question with their response

Answer (score 2):

if you want PHP to use a specific version of libcurl, your best bet is to compile libcurl and PHP manually. the specific steps to build libcurl & php is specific to the OS you're using (Windows? Linux? Mac? *BSD?), but since you mentioned `php_curl.dll` which is only relevant on Windows, i guess you're using windows? in which case, first find your preferred libcurl version here https://github.com/curl/curl/releases and compile it as described here https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html and compile PHP against it as described here https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild_sdk_2 with the additional steps found here https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php

(eg, you have to add the parameter `--with-curl="C:\path\to\compiled\libcurl"` to php's `configure` script)

Comment: That's kinda hard to do for a guy that only uses PHP. PHP aknowledged the bug here https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78162 I will wait for a patch to come, And Will use php 7.0